# КАк сделать бегущую строку с таким контентом?

Tags: javascript

КАк сделать бегущую строку с таким контентом?

```html
<div class="text">
  <span>text 1</span>
  <span>text 2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, есть такой старый html-тег `marquee`:

```css
.text {
  background-color: #242424;
  padding: .3em 0;
  max-width: 300px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: tomato;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-shadow: 0 0 .2em tomato;
}
```

```html
<marquee class="text">
  <span>text 1</span>
  <span>text 2</span>
</marquee>
```

Еще можно через css-анимации:

```css
@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    left: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.marquee {
  width: fit-content;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  animation: marquee 5s infinite linear;
}

.text {  
  background-color: #242424;
  padding: .3em 0;
  width: 300px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: tomato;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-shadow: 0 0 .2em tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <div class="marquee">
    <span>text 1</span>
    <span>text 2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Он же [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee)

Comment: Да, но вопрос не блещет подробностями. Добавил вариант с css-анимацией.

Comment: Тег `<marquee>` делает все сам. У него еще есть атрибуты для настройки. Но вообще, как заметили выше, тег очень старый и не рекомендован к использованию.

Comment: @novvember спасибо, что уделили время, я уже ознакомился со ссылкой выше.

Comment: @novvember, спасибо. Второй вариант подошел. только можно как-то сделать чтобы не приходилось дублировать в коде спаны? ведь 2 спана изначально разные .а потом они повторяются. Поняли о чем я?

Comment: Спаны не повторяются, я просто добавил, чтобы больше текста было. Убрал лишние спаны, оставил только два.

Comment: @novvember, не это имелось ввиду.имелось ввиду , чтобы они заполнялись по ширине контейнера.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю такой простенький вариант:

```css
.marquee {
  width: 50%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.marquee .content {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%;
  animation: marquee 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <div class="content">
    <span>text 1</span>
    <span>text 2</span>
    <span>text 3</span>
    <span>text 4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Больше примеров [тут](https://www.babulya.com.ua/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-html-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3-marquee/) и [тут](https://www.quackit.com/css/codes/marquees/)